# Accessing Many to Many Relationships with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

So the issue I am having is accessing and using data from a many to many relationships, I am using Laravel in October cms.

I have Owners and ManyToMany objects with a `pivot table` using `owner_id and manytomany_id`. I can access `OneToMany relationship` just fine using the code below, but trying to access `ManyToMany objects` I cant assign them, this is the code I'm using,

```
    foreach ($this->owners as $owner) {
        $owner['onetomany'] = $owner->onetomany()->take($this->maxJobs)->get();
        $owner['manytomany'] = $owner->manytomany()->take($this->maxTeam)->get();    
    }
```

my relationships are both defined as so

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'manytomany' => [
        'Kai\Relations\Models\ManyToMany', 
        'table' => 'kai_relations_owner_many_to_many'
    ]
];
public $belongsToMany = [
    'owner' => [
        'Kai\Relations\Models\Owner', 
        'table' => 'kai_relations_owner_many_to_many'
    ]
];
```

if I define a page variable such as `$this->something`, it will not allow me to assign the results of the ManyToMany query, but if I assign the results to just $something, I can Log the results and see the returned data, so why can't I access it?

The reason I'm not Eager loading these results is the need to limit the number of items, which after much research I found could not be done with eager loading.

This is the error i receive:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `kai_relations_many_to_manies` where `id` in (?))
```

If anyone can shed any light on this it would be a lot of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($this->owners as $owner) {
        $owner['onetomany'] = $owner->onetomany()->take($this->maxJobs)->get();
        $owner['manytomany'] = $owner->manytomany()->take($this->maxTeam)->get();    
    }
```

I think This is not working because you have defined relationship already with name **`manytomany`** So it will try to override your **manytomany** with data you are trying to retrieve with `$owner->manytomany()->take($this->maxTeam)->get();`

Now you can change the name from `$owner['manytomany']` to something different than your relationship name i.e **`$owner['ownerManyToMany']`** and then may be you can get your data.

Try this

```
foreach ($this->owners as $owner) {
        $owner['onetomany'] = $owner->onetomany()->take($this->maxJobs)->get();
        $owner['ownerManyToMany'] = $owner->manytomany()->take($this->maxTeam)->get();    
    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly but is this a sensible way to retrieve limited records from a one-to-many and many-to-many relationship? i tried eager loading but you cannot limit relationships on a collection with eager loading.

Comment: Do you want to get limited records globally or just for a particular function only?

Comment: @KaiForward If you want limited records globally then you can use [Example filter using scope](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#detailed-relationships). Otherwise, if you want for a particular function this is the best way. And if you think my answer is correct then please mark my answer as accepted and upvote to as an appreciation :)

Comment: thanks i have accepted the answer, and upvoted but unfortunately i'm too low level for it to show up publicly!
Thats great to know, i needed to do it for a particular function as im using it in a component that has variable limit's set my admin, so this is the perfect solution!

Comment: i see by your profile you like to help many many people! well done! and your plugins look very nice!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many say that relation have a pivot table and in this table have columns with reference to table to make a manytomany relation.

for example on migration file:

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('product_id');
});;
```

In Product  model:

```
public function extraCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

In Category Model:

```
public function extraProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Other examples on model:

```
public function associacion()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_related', 'product2_id', 'product_id');
}
```

In this case, has a specific table, first column and second column, that Eloquent not make automatically connexion with pivot table and other model.

When you get data for example with tinker you can see:

```
App\Product {#892
     id: "4555",
     name: "PRODUCT NAME",
     extraCategories: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#912
       all: [
         App\Category {#907
           id: "245",
           description: "YYYYY",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#902
             product_id: "4555",
             category_id: "245",
           },
         },
         App\Category {#908
           id: "135",
           description: "XXXXX",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#901
             product_id: "4555",
             category_id: "135",
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
```

In this case returned extraCategories relation many to many on array of collections.

I hope of this solved your problems.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, it seems like i have set-up correctly the method to acess many to many relationships as you have described, but i cannot cast that data to page variable that i can access, for example:
`$something = $owner->manytomany()` <-this works
but:
`$owner['manytomany'] = $owner->manytomany();` <- gives this error


`Object of class October\Rain\Database\Relations\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string`

Comment: It seems i cannot override relations that are loaded automatically, i try to load `$owner['random_name'] = $owner->manytomany();` it works, but when i try to place data in `['manytomany']` attribute of the model, it doesn't work